# Unsubscribing a LocationListener from the LocationManager

Tags: android, locationmanager, locationlistener

How do I unsubscribe a `LocationListener` from recieving updates from the `LocationManager`?

Here is how I'm setting it up

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
mListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("LocationListener", "Logging Change");
    }

}

mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                5000, 1, mListener);
```

After I have exited the the view that created the `LocationListener` I am still getting log messages in the LogCat window.

I understand that this is because I am orphaning the listener but I cannot see any destroy method on the `LocationListener` nor can I see any "remove listener" style methods on the `LocationManager` object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call [removeUpdates](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener)) on LocationManager, passing your location listener.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this if you are not storing the listener as a member?

Answer (score 6):

```
mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mListener);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think [removeUpdates](http://dev.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29) should help.

```
mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mListener)
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing this if you are not storing the listener as a member?